# Como sumar un atributo de un objeto repetido dentro de un arrayList

Tags: java, poo, arraylist

tengo la siguiente tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que se sumen los valores de los objetos repetidos por su ID, y se muestre solo uno, por ejemplo.
En la columna "Costumer ID" se repite 6 veces el id "811.045.749.3" la idea es que se sume el valor de la columna "Total" por cada vez que se repita.
Este es mi metodo:

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Row currentRow = iterator.next();
                if (i > 0) {
                    if (currentRow.getCell(0)
                            != null && currentRow.getCell(1)
                            != null && currentRow.getCell(2)
                            != null && currentRow.getCell(3)
                            != null && currentRow.getCell(4)
                            != null && currentRow.getCell(5)
                            != null && currentRow.getCell(6)
                            != null && currentRow.getCell(7)
                            != null && currentRow.getCell(8)
                            != null && currentRow.getCell(9)
                            != null && currentRow.getCell(10)
                            != null) {
                        debtFileTO.setCustomerID(currentRow.getCell(4).getStringCellValue());
                        debtFileTO.setCustomerNombre(currentRow.getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
                        debtFileTO.setCustomerEmail(currentRow.getCell(9).getStringCellValue());
                        debtFileTO.setCustomerPhone(currentRow.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
                        debtFileTO.setTotalDeuda(currentRow.getCell(8).getNumericCellValue());
                        debtFileTOs.add(debtFileTO);
                        debtFileTO = new DebtFileTO();
                        PrimeFaces.current().executeScript(mensajewall);
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sencilla sería utilizar un Map donde la Key sería el valor del ID y el valor el acumulado.

en tu caso sería un Map<String,Double>. Cuando recorres las filas validas si el id está en el map, si está lo sumas y si no lo añades.

Algo así:

```
Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<String, Double>();
if(map.containsKey(id)) {
    map.put(key, map.get(id)+totalAmount);
}else {
    map.put(id, value);
}
```

Un saludo!